# How to prevent git merge upstream to delete files

Tags: git

I forked a project which has a specific folder. (app/themes/theme_name)

Since, the folder was deleted from the main repository.

I need to preserve the folder in my current project (cause I am still working on it).
Basically I want to be able to merge my upstream without deleting files I'm still using.

One solution would be to rename files but I think it will loose the history.

Is there another solution? Thanks

- update : merge not fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If git's merge does almost exactly what you want, often the best way to get exactly what you want is to run it `--no-commit` and fix up the result manually:

```
git merge --no-commit
git checkout HEAD -- app/themes/theme_name
git commit
```

Nothing says you have to use git's default merge driver at all, and git's built so its merge cooperates very well with usage like this.

Answer (score 0):

make these files not to be tracked by git

```
git rm --cached filename
```

Comment: Sorry it's a merge not a fetch. Just update my question. the git rm --cached filename should be to applied to the main repo?

Comment: @benoitr well, maybe you can make a copy of a folder, update your project and then use your folder without adding it to git tracked files